# Understanding of Capacitive Voltage Divider

Tags: circuit-analysis, capacitor, analog

This may be a stupid question, but it really confuses me. Suppose there are two capacitors connected in series like this (C0=C1=1pF, define Vx=the voltage of the intermediate node):

```
       C0      C1
Vin -----||------||------GND
```

\$\ V_{in} = 1 + sin(\omega t)\$, which is a sin wave with a DC offset. \$\ V_x= \frac{1}{2}sin(\omega t)\$ according to my simulation result, but what is the explanation of this in the time domain?

I read some posts saying that the charge on the two capacitors are the same in this case, and equals to the integral of current. I calculated \$ \frac{1}{C} \int i \cdot dt \$ in the simulator and found it is exactly the voltage at the intermediate node - this makes sensor for C1 because the voltage difference is \$\ V_x-0\$, which is \$\ V_x\$ itself. However, this doesn't make sense for C0, because the voltage across C0 is \$ V_{in}-V_x \$, shouldn't \$ \frac{1}{C} \int i \cdot dt = V_{in} - V_x \$ (according to the equation \$\ Q=C\cdot V\$)?

Comment: How does your simulator handle the initial DC condition or ignore it? If it simply assumes there is 1V bias on C0, there is no problem as you can have a capacitor with such initial conditions that it is charged to 1V ober it, so it has filtered away the DC.

Comment: @Justme Yes, the simulator must have added a 1V bias on C0 as I didn't specified the initial condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but what is the explanation of this in the time domain?

Without an inital condition, you'll never know what Vx is. Vx is *floating* for an ideal capacitor this means it could anything. The parallel resistance is infinite for an ideal capacitor, so this means the DC value will be indeterminate. If you know the initial condition, it wouldn't be 1/2 it would be whatever it started out as and then the sine wave added on top.

In the real world you can't have something floating like this because material has resistance and all capacitors have parallel resistance. So in the real world it would be ~1/2.

Comment: @ Voltage Spike - your answer is contrary to Franc`s answer below (Vx prop. to 1/Cx) .  Please, could you comment on this discreapency?

Answer (score 2):

You state that

> Vin = 1 + sin(w*t)

By default, this means that this voltage not only will be applied in all future times, but has been eternally present in the past. For frequency analysis, this is what we want -- pure, eternal sine waves (with DC being a sine wave of frequency 0). But for transient analysis, this will will not work.

For transient analysis, we might say that

Vin = 0 for all times t < t0,
Vin = 1 + sin(wt) for all times t > t0

Let's *assume* that the capacitors are uncharged for all times t < t0 (t0 = 1 ms in this example). Then the transient voltage of the intermediate node Vx will look like this.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnHGyT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

Exactly half of the applied voltage V1.

But this simulation has an ideal method for measuring the voltage that requires no current. Let's make the circuit more realistic, by adding a resistance at the output of the divider to represent the resistance of the multimeter, or the effects of the bias current of an op-amp.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1njJi.png)</sup>

[image]

Two things have changed. One change is that the amplitude of the sine wave is smaller. This is because the impedance of the 1 pF capacitor at the 1 kHz we arbitrarily chose for w, is greater than the 10 M\$\Omega\$ resistor we have added to the circuit, representing the measurement device. The second change is that the DC component has quickly vanished!

Let's increase the size of our capacitors, so that the 10 M\$\Omega\$ resistor does not load the voltage divider as much.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLtd11.png)</sup>

[image]

The amplitude of the sine wave is now hardly attenuated, and the DC component decays much more slowly, but it still decays. If we let the simulation run a little longer, we get this:

[image]

In general, UNLESS WE PERIODICALLY RESET THE CHARGE IN THE CAPACITORS, a DC component in a capacitative voltage divider, with a resistive load, will decay. The rate at which it decays is determined by the RC timing constant, so the larger the capacitors, and the larger the resistor, the slower the decay.

Answer (score 1):

Analysis of a capacitive divider where the type of independent generator is not specified and with non-zero initial conditions. You can adapt it to the case of two capacitors:

[image]
[image]